# Mix Blend Mode is not working on iPhone and iPad browser

Tags: css, iphone, web, ipad, mix-blend-mode

I am working on a website project.
I put the image and set mix-blend-mode: screen.
It works well on all browsers except iPhone and iPad browser.
Please let me know solution.
Thanks & Regards.

I am not sure why this happen in only iPhone and iPad web browser.

Comment: We can’t really help without seeing the relevant code. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd like to share my solution, hoping it might help others:

To address the problem, I adjusted the `img` I intended to multiply so that it became a sibling element to the `img` I was multiplying with.

As of December 2023, this appears to be the only effective method that works on iPhone's Google Chrome and Safari browsers.

In essence transform the code from:

```
<div class="main">
  <div class="container">
    <img style="mix-blend-mode: multiply;" src="./multiply.png" />
  </div>
  <img  src="./background.png" />
</div>
```

to

```
<div class="main container">
  <img style="mix-blend-mode: multiply;" src="./multiply.png" />
  <img  src="./background.png" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Same thing here. "Mix-blend-mode: multiply" is working on computer browsers (everyone I tested), Samsung browser and Android Chrome but not in iPad/iPhone Safari or Chrome. I paste my code here but I think it's not about the code itself but Apple OS issue with this property.

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="content">
    <!-- Card content -->
  </div>
  <div id="red-background"></div> <!-- empty div for transparent effect -->
</div>



#red-background {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  background: url(../imgs/fondo-rojo.jpg);
  background-repeat: repeat;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  // background-color: #F40009;
  mix-blend-mode: multiply;
  // background-blend-mode: multiply;
  border-radius: 50px;
}
```

I tried both properties: "background-color" and "background" with a red little jpg but none of them have worked. Same thing with "mix-blend-mode" and "background-blend-mode".

Comment: In case it can help anyone: I fixed it after so much try-and-error. I moved the layer which has the image to the div that contains the multiplied element. Now it makes sense to me, but I still don't understand why it works everywhere but iPhone or iPad.